# Pydantic datetime is stored as String in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pydantic

I am trying to store some date in Mongo collection but it is stored as String in MongoDB.

This is the model:

```
def datetime_now() -> datetime:
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc)    
class Project(BaseModel):
    id: uuid.UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4, alias="_id")
    title: str = Field(constr(max_length=30))
    description: str = Field(constr(max_length=200))
    createdAt: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime_now)
    updatedAt: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime_now)
    createdBy: Optional[str] = None
    updatedBy: Optional[str] = None
    archived: Optional[bool] = False
    deleted: Optional[bool] = False
```

Here, `createdAt` field is stored as String in MongoDB. But I want createdAt to be stored as mongo Date field.

[image]

For reference, please check this image. Here **createdAt** is manually set as Date, while updatedAt is `dateAsString`.

Code for saving into mongo is:

```
@router.post(
    "/",
    response_description="Create a new project",
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
    response_model=[],
)
def create_project(
    request: Request,
    project: Project = Body(...),
    Authorization: Optional[str] = Header(None),
):
    print(request.state.jwt_content)
    project = jsonable_encoder(project)
    project['createdBy'] = request.state.jwt_content['emp_code']
    project['updatedBy'] = request.state.jwt_content['emp_code']
    new_project = request.app.database["projects"].insert_one(project)
    created_project = request.app.database["projects"].find_one(
        {"_id": new_project.inserted_id}
    )
    return created_project
```

Comment: What do you want to do? It's not clear in the question what you want to archive...

Comment: I want that the createdDate i am passing to mongodb, should be stored as mongodb Date field, but as now it is stored as a String.

Comment: Added an image for clear understanding of problem

Comment: How are you storing this in MongoDB?

Comment: @AKX, I have added pydantic model above. Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: Show the code that saves this in MongoDB.

Comment: Added, the code

Comment: @raju You're using `jsonable_encoder(project)` - that turns your datetimes into strings (since they can be encoded as JSON). Maybe use `project.model_dump()` instead and let your MongoDB adapter deal with data conversion.

Answer (score -1):

I have read this article: [How to prepare a Python date object to be stored in MongoDB and run queries by dates and range of dates.](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-prepare-a-python-date-object-to-be-inserted-into-mongodb-and-run-queries-by-dates-and-range-bc0da03ea0b2)

And this basically says you have to use the correct format for BSON:

> MongoDB has no special datetime object and it uses the JavaScript Date type, which is stored in BSON form. Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). The official BSON specification refers to the BSON Date type as the UTC datetime. BSON Date type is signed. Negative values represent dates before 1970.

> Date() returns the current date as a string in the mongo shell.

> new Date() returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in UTC.

> MongoDB automatically wrapped dates with the function: ISODate(). ISODate() is a built-in function that wraps the native JavaScript Date object providing a convenient way to represent dates in a human-readable format preserving the full use of dates queries and indexing.
> So, out of the box, MongoDB gives a default ISO representation for dates. Should you need a format different from the ISO one, you need to convert yourself on the client-side.

So you need to convert your Date Object to ISO8261 - standard.

[How to get ISO 8601 Datetime in Python](https://pynative.com/python-iso-8601-datetime/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20datetime%20to%20ISO%208601%20format%20use%20the%20isoformat,to%20the%20corresponding%20time%20zone.)

Here's an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# get current datetime
today = datetime.now()
print('Today Datetime:', today)

# Get current ISO 8601 datetime in string format
iso_date = today.isoformat()
print('ISO DateTime:', iso_date)
```

Hope this helps